# How can I quickly create a dictionary with multiple keys to the same value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create this dictionary:

```
nonleap_year = {
    1: 31,
    2: 28,
    3: 31,
    4: 30,
    5: 31,
    6: 30,
    7: 31,
    8: 31,
    9: 30,
    10: 31,
    11: 30,
    12: 31,
}
```

But I am not satisfied with typing out the repeated values.

I tried to do it this way, and it didn't work:

```
nonleap_year = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12: 31, 4, 6, 9, 11: 30, 2: 28}
```

Python considers this to be a set, and the colon should not appear here. What would be the simplest way to achieve this goal?

The best method I know now is to use `dict.fromkeys` to create two dictionaries and then merge them.

Comment: what is the problem in creating the dictionary in the top? sure, you could try a formula that assigns each month the correct days, but we are talking about only 12 entries here. Just hardcode the dictionary. Looking at the top dictionry I can immediately see that is months and days (despite the poor variable name), looking at the bottom one will make me spend precious time figuring out what are you trying to do.

Comment: How about: _dict = {(1,3,5,7,8,10,12):31,(4,6,9,11):30,(2,):28} That's syntactically correct (keys are tuples). Not sure how you'd use it though

Comment: the reason why your approach can't work is because your notation is ambigous, since you use `,` for separating `(key, value)` pairs _and_ for separating keys within a `(key, value)` pair

Comment: @DarkKnight I also considered that approach, but if OP still wants to write sth like `my_dict[month]` to get the number of days, it would require to subclass `dict` and overwrite `__getitem__` and at that point, hardcoding the dict with 12 `(key, value)` pairs is more concise

Comment: OP, you should probably give more context: as it seems, you are not working with arbitrary but very specific data -- your keys seem to be months, your values seem to be the number of days in the corresponding months, and different dictionaries seem to refer to different years (regular and leap years). With this knowledge, a tailored answer is probably better than a general answer.

Answer (score 3):

Make a reverse mapping first - key that represents value in a final dict with a list of all the keys that should have this value:

```
d = {
    31: [1,3,5,7,8,10,12],
    30: [4,6,9,11],
    28: [2]
}
```

Than make a dict comprehension to reverse that mapping:

```
d_rev = {v:k for k,li in d.items() for v in li}

print(d_rev)
```

Output:

```
{1: 31, 3: 31, 5: 31, 7: 31, 8: 31, 10: 31, 12: 31, 4: 30, 6: 30, 9: 30, 11: 30, 2: 28}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed method using `dict.fromkeys` sounds reasonable. You can merge them in a single expression using dictionary unpacking syntax:

```
{**dict.fromkeys([1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12], 31), **dict.fromkeys([4, 6, 9, 11], 30), 2: 28}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromkeys#dict.fromkeys)

```
dict.fromkeys((1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12), 31) | \
dict.fromkeys((4,6,9,11), 30) | \
dict.fromkeys((2,), 28)
# Out:
# {1: 31,
#  3: 31,
#  5: 31,
#  7: 31,
#  8: 31,
#  10: 31,
#  12: 31,
#  4: 30,
#  6: 30,
#  9: 30,
#  11: 30,
#  2: 28}
```

The expression `d | other` takes care of merging two dictionaries
whereas the values of `other` take priority when `d` and `other` share keys.

Answer (score 2):

###### Use [`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) function

Rather than manually writing each value, for this particular case you can use a function like [`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) from the calendar module. You can pass year and month as parameters and get the number of days in a month. `monthrange` returns weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month, for the specified month of a year.

```
from calendar import monthrange as days
{k: days(2023, k)[-1] for k in range(1, 13)}
```

Output:

```
{1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}
```

Comment: I was about to downvote your comment because I could not understand in which way it relates to the question -- until I noticed the pattern in OP's data (i.e. OP is working with years, months, and days in months). Maybe you should add a clarifying comment to your solution, as it is probably the best one, so far, but not very obvious when only reading it briefly.

Comment: This indeed solves the specific problem at hand, but in a more general sense, this approach might not work when multiple keys correspond to the same value.